# Programmatically change Windows power settings

Tags: c#, windows, acpi

Is it possible to change the power-saving behaviour of a laptop computer on lid close from *hibernate/standby/shutdown* to *Do Nothing* from the .NET Framework?

**Edit:** it would appear that by setting the value to Standby and blocking the standby from my application, the lid close event can be detected, which is what I'm really after.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355606/detect-laptop-lid-closure-and-opening) which deals with detecting lid close, but it boils down to using a standby event or writing a driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the WMI classes.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to an introduction to WMI

Note that you can also use `Application.SetSuspendState`, but this method only allows you to suspend or hibernate. So I guess it doesn't match your needs...

About the lid, there seems to be [a way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/doronh/archive/2006/09/08/746834.aspx) to detect if the lid is closed or not...

Comment: AFAIK you need to write a driver to detect the `SYS_BUTTON_LID` message via `IOCTL_GET_SYS_BUTTON_EVENT`, but that would warrant a separate question.