# How can I detect the laptop lid opening/closure using Python run under Windows?

Tags: python, windows

How can I detect the laptop lid opening/closure using Python run under Windows?

Comment: Not sure, but combine this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355606/detect-laptop-lid-closure-and-opening and this: http://ironpython.net/

Comment: There does not seem to be a specific lid open/close action, really. Depending on Power Management settings, the action trips that event. For instance, I am not sure if you can actually detect lid open/close in windows, but if lid close triggers system sleep, you can detect the system sleep.