# Detect laptop current lid state by C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi

I'm writing a C++ app, and I want to get the current lid state of the laptop.
Note: not catch an event of the lid state changing, but once `main()` is executed, get the current lid state.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Get current laptop lid state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26869987/7478597)

Answer (score -3):

The implementation how to get lid state by C#.
https://github.com/rowandh/lidstatusservice

I think that shouldn't be problematic to translate the code to C++.

Comment: That solution is not querying the current lid status. It is launching a background service that calls `RegisterPowerSettingNotification()` to receive `PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE` notifications looking for `GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE` events: "*The state of the lid has changed (open or closed).*" The OP stated they did not want to handle events.

Comment: @RemyLebeau With all respect, docs says - "Immediately after registration, the callback will be invoked with the current value of the power setting.". I. e. it is possible to get the current setting value with RegisterPowerSettingNotification.

Comment: @n0ne still doesn't change the fact that the OP didn't want to handle events just to get the value